# Prestashop Multistore Move Cart attending Postal Code

Tags: prestashop

In a multistore prestashop every store is a different company, with different payment methods. What I need to do is to check  the postal code, and if is in a range, move the order to another store and continue the cheout from this store. Is this possible? If not, what other options I have (this stores are covering a small portion of postal codes where they send the product).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do so it can be possible by making a new module and checking user input on Zip code field by jQuery, send this zip code to front controller by ajax request and if it matches any of zip code simply change 'cart' and 'cart_product' tables shop id to new shop id you are sending the customer to. make a redirect to other store including the controller url of module and parameters like "domain-new.com/restore?cart_id=23"

Get cart id from this url from created module front controller and make redirect in

```
init() like

$id_cart = (int)Tools::getValue('id_cart');
$this->context->cookie->id_cart = $id_cart;
$link_order = $this->context->link->getPageLink('order');
Tools::redirect($link_order);
```

Ofcourse you need to know programming to do so otherwise this idea is useless to you.

Comment: I know programming but have very poor knowledge about Prestashop. I will study your solution, can you say me where to do this programming algorithm?

Comment: Make new module which should have front controller which will be used to receive ajax requests also hook some JS file into header. in '/themes/your_theme_name/order-opc-new-account.tpl' find ZIP code field and add onkeyup event to trigger function in your JS file which will send ajax request containing zip code.

Comment: I am trying to dev the module. What hook is the right to include the JS?